Polynom with complex coefficients
Consider the equation $x^3 - e^{-2ia}(6e^{3ia} - ib)x^2 + e^{-ia}(5e^{3ia} - 6ib)x + 5ib = 0$. I need to solve it for x. The equation has one quite obvious root $e^{ia}$. So one can just devide the left side polynomial by $x - e^{ia}$ and solve the quadratic equation in a standard way. But this solution seems too straightforward and tedious. May be there is more elegant and pretty way to factor the polynomial

The form of the polynomial suggests changing variables to $x = e^{ia}y$. Doing this and clearing the coefficient of $y^3$ gives
$$
y^3 - (6 - i b e^{-3ia}) y^2 +(5-6ibe^{-3ia})y +5ibe^{3ia} = 0.
$$
Letting $c = -ibe^{-3ia}$ for brevity, we can factor this polynomial as
$$
y^3 - (c+6) y^2 +(5+ 6c)y - 5c = (y - c)(y^2 - 6y + 5) = (y - c)(y - 1)(y - 5) = 0,
$$
which clearly solves to $y = 1, 5, c$. Converting back to the original variables gives
$$
x = e^{ia}, 5e^{ia}, -ibe^{-2ia}.
$$
